# iOS Enterprise Deployement: Clicking on itms-services link results in “Cannot connect to [domain]” error

Tags: php, ios, iphone, plist, ipa

I have uploaded following file in server's root folder

appname.ipa

appname.plist

appname.png

index.php

In appname.plist file content as following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://subdomain.domain.com/appname.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.appname.enterprise</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Appname</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Link that i used in index.php

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=https://subdomain.domain.com/appname.plist"> click this link to install </a>
```

I have also added all needed mime types in etc/mime.types

```
application/octet-stream        bin lha lzh exe class so dll img iso ipa
application/xml plist
text/xml                    xml plist
```

Also I have SSL certificate.

Is this the problem because I am using subdomain?